# Ruby on Rails. Returning output of exe file to browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, popen3

First time using Ruby or Rails, so bear with me :) I am trying to output the results of an exe file to my browser, possibly with some processing before hand. I am using Open3

```
@stdout,@stderr,@status = Open3.capture3('c:\server.exe','')
```

This works, but the output only seems to return anything when the exe file has finished, eg if its closed manually, or if it returns an error.

What actually happens when I execute the file is a server runs and returns info to the console. I need this data in the console while its running, not after.

**My question:** How do I return, process, and display each line from the console in real time? Is that even possible?

Comment: See the SSH gem source code. It is clear, easy to re-use in your own app, and is the best example I know for getting terminal output as it happens. (I had the same issue you did, and the SSH gem code solved mine).

Comment: I believe it's possible with rails 4, but not with rails 3 of less. First thing is you to use a development server that allow streaming, the default webrick cannot do it for example. See this article and you can get some more info http://www.sitepoint.com/streaming-with-rails-4/ Sorry for not being more helpful but I haven't done it yet

Comment: Another source of inspiration is this railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/266-http-streaming?view=asciicast